# Angular 2+ NgTemplateOutlet inside ngFor

Tags: angular, angular2-template, ngfor, ng-template, angular2-ngcontent

We have some arrays like:

- `heroes: Hero[];`
- `villains: Villain[];`
- ...
- `puppies: Puppy[]`

and a template like

```
<p *ngFor="let individual of heroes">
    {{ individual.name }} - {{ individual.mobileNumber }}
    ...
</p>
    <p *ngFor="let individual of villains">
    {{ individual.name }} - {{ individual.mobileNumber }}
    ...
</p>
...
 <p *ngFor="let individual of puppies">
    {{ individual.name }} - {{ individual.mobileNumber }}
    ...
</p>
```

The `*ngFor` loops have all the same content. To simplify that we create one `ng-template` that we can reuse.

```
<ng-template let-individual #individualParagraphContent>
    {{ individual.name }} - {{ individual.mobileNumber }}
    ...
<ng-template>
```

Now we want to use it like e.g.:

```
<p *ngFor="let individual of puppies">
  <ng-content *ngTemplateOutlet="individualParagraphContent;
              context: {individual: individual}">
  </ng-content>
</p>
```

Here I failed. I found examples where the whole `*ngFor` loop is in the template and how to pass a value from the component itself, but i did not manage to insert a `<ng-template>` into a for loop and to pass the variable(individual) correct.

**EDIT**
Solved. Everything was fine but the initialization in the `ng-template`

```
<ng-template let-individual="individual" #individualParagraphContent>
```

Answer (score 17):

Try something like this :

```
<ng-container
    *ngFor="let individual of heroes"
    [ngTemplateOutlet]="individualParagraphContent"
    [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{individual: individual}"></ng-container>
```

and for the template :

```
<ng-template let-individual="individual" #individualParagraphContent>
    <p>
       {{ individual.name }} - {{ individual.mobileNumber }}
       ...
    </p>
<ng-template>
```

let-(x)="key for x in the context"

Comment: thanks for ur answer! as soon as we use `[ngTemplateOutlet]=` instead of `*ngTemplateOutlet=` the template does not get rendered anymore it seems... i tried using `ngTemplateOutletContext` in different ways, but still i did not find the correct one /:

Comment: ah but still thanks to answer i found the solution! everything in the example from the question was fine but the template.
wrong: `<ng-template let-individual #individualParagraphContent>`
correct: `<ng-template let-individual="individual" #individualParagraphContent>`

thanks!

Comment: Yeah sorry, the `[ngTemplateOutlet]` is used in the case of a `ngFor*` :

`<ng-container *ngFor="let individual of puppies"
             [ngTemplateOutlet]="individualParagraphContent"
             [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{
                individual: individual
              }"></ng-container>`