# how can I inject a component inside a loop

Tags: angular, angular2-template

we can inject an Angular component dynamically `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()` where `ViewContainerRef` refers to a template reference like this `<ng-template #ref>`

how can we achieve the same approach, but when the template reference is created inside a loop, like this

```
@for(item of items; track item){
  <div>
   <!-- some nested markups -->

   <!-- inject each item's component here -->
   <!-- this should be created several times, once for each item -->
   <ng-template #ref></ng-template> 
 </div>
}
```

```
items = [
  component1,
  component2
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2+ NgTemplateOutlet inside ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51962304/angular-2-ngtemplateoutlet-inside-ngfor)

Comment: I'm going to check it now and tell you if it answers my question. thank you for your suggestion  @possum

Answer (score 1):

You can use ngComponentOutlet. https://angular.io/api/common/NgComponentOutlet

Example:

```
@for (component of components; track $index) {
    <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="component"></ng-container>
}
```